# MySql Query to Array to MySql IN Query

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to make an array of IDs and use that array in another query to make sure the 2nd query results have the same ids that are in the array.

As per the requirements of the rest of my code, I would prefer not to use the join method.

```
    $topartistsquery = "SELECT main_id FROM pages WHERE catnum = '201' AND top100 = 'y'";
    $result = mysql_query($topartistsquery);
    $topartistarray = array();
    while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
        $topartistarray[] = $row['main_id'];
    }
    //print_r($topartistarray);

    $eventquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TNDB_CSV2 WHERE City = '".$city."' AND PCatID = '2' AND PerformerID IN ($topartistarray) AND DateTime >= CURDATE() ORDER BY DateTime LIMIT 3");
```

Here is the output of the $topartistarray:

```
Array ( [0] => 28 [1] => 1126 [2] => 47643 [3] => 2769 [4] => 41512 [5] => 1429 [6] => 163 [7] => 48418 [8] => 198 [9] => 3748 [10] => 10161 [11] => 39890 [12] => 14160 [13] => 25407 [14] => 29219 [15] => 36980 [16] => 1860 [17] => 41299 [18] => 342 [19] => 7468 [20] => 33205 [21] => 1564 [22] => 33911 [23] => 15183 [24] => 540 [25] => 974 [26] => 8358 [27] => 30678 [28] => 4804 [29] => 4266 [30] => 517 [31] => 522 [32] => 1550 [33] => 15989 [34] => 930 [35] => 3383 [36] => 26468 [37] => 5560 [38] => 1063 [39] => 2870 [40] => 4055 [41] => 24917 [42] => 46223 [43] => 973 [44] => 334 [45] => 27970 [46] => 27985 [47] => 356 [48] => 6655 [49] => 201 [50] => 1930 [51] => 1069 [52] => 38053 [53] => 397 [54] => 21713 [55] => 53725 [56] => 4941 [57] => 864 [58] => 41904 [59] => 59233 [60] => 53970 [61] => 50875 [62] => 54175 [63] => 56861 [64] => 53317 [65] => 55258 [66] => 823 [67] => 55704 [68] => 59797 [69] => 27866 [70] => 123 [71] => 59749 [72] => 1567 [73] => 34851 [74] => 3399 [75] => 58674 [76] => 59442 [77] => 60334 )
```

Any constructive input is greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you avoiding joins? Would simplify this whole scenario greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (isset($topartistarray) and count($topartistarray) {
    $eventquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TNDB_CSV2 WHERE City = '".$city."' AND PCatID = '2' AND PerformerID IN (".implode(",",$topartistarray).") AND DateTime >= CURDATE() ORDER BY DateTime LIMIT 3");
} else {
    $eventquery = false;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, I knew it had to be something simple, it usually always is.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_query` and `mysql_*` functions. It's not secure and in the next release of PHP this functions will be removed. Use mysqli (mysqlnd) or better PDO with prepared statements instead.

Comment: a word of caution, check for count($topartistarray) before running this query or you'll end up with an empty IN ()

Comment: Good idea, I always have results for that query but it's good insurance.  Thanks again.